# django - persist instant for every session

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

I am using `ajax` to classify users dynamically by some algorithm within a class called `classifyByNavigation` that take the navigation data of a user as input and try to suggest something to the user based on this data.

this class looks like:

```py
class classifyByNavigation:

  def __init__(self, user_id):
    self.navigationdata = []
    self.user_id = user_id

  def suggest(navigation_):
    self.navigationdata.append(navigation_)
    to_propose = MyAlgorthm(self.navigationdata)
    return to_propose
```

This class is called by a script `myAjax.py` which is called by the client side (javascript). This is not the problem!

Every user should have a persistent instance of `classifyByNavigation` that will record his navigation data along the session and suggest something based on that.

Any idea how do it? If I declare a new instance in the method inside `myAjax.py` so I will loose the `navigationdata` because the method will be called more than once.

Comment: Try to store the classifyByNavigation instance in the [user session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/sessions/)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. An example will be helpful.. Regards

Comment: Is the navigation data that you are storing just strings like URLs or something similar?